# query in mysql with node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am trying to get comments likes and dislike in post but i cant get comments in `strings`

```
SELECT p.*, u.full_name as post_author,c.*,l.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.comment SEPARATOR ',') as comments, GROUP_CONCAT(u3.id SEPARATOR '#') as post_likers FROM post p LEFT JOIN posts_comments c ON c.post_id = p.id LEFT JOIN post_like_dislike l ON l.post_id = p.id  LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = p.user_id LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = c.user_id LEFT JOIN user u3 ON u3.id = l.user_id   GROUP BY p.id
```

i have tried this query but getting the proper result

.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seRMj.jpg)

i am getting comments like this but i want comments with user name and comment ..
there are 3 different tables comments post and like

i want to get all comment of a post in post and in `string` or `json` form[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMzGL.png)
like this .. i am using node `JS` with mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you want a SQL-only solution, try this

```
SELECT p.*, u.full_name as post_author,c.*,l.*,
IF(c.id IS NOT NULL, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', c.id, 'comment', c.comment)), NULL) AS comments,
IF(u3.id IS NOT NULL, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', u3.id)), NULL) AS post_likers
FROM post p 
LEFT JOIN posts_comments c ON c.post_id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN post_like_dislike l ON l.post_id = p.id  
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = p.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN user u3 ON u3.id = l.user_id   
GROUP BY p.id
```

**Note**: there are many ORM out there already handle query relationship like this, give it a try.